# what is wrong with the code below?

Tags: php, point

Question page

```
<html>
<head><title>ex41a</title></head>
<body>
<form method="post" name="ex41a" action="ex41b.php">
<hr>
Q1: Who made this question? <br>
<input type="radio" name="1ans" value="Spiderman"> Spiderman <br>
<input type="radio" name="1ans" value="Ed"> Ed <br>
<input type="radio" name="1ans" value="Superman"> Superman <br>
<input type="radio" name="1ans" value="The Hulk"> The Hulk <br>
<hr>
Q2: What is this for? <br>
<input type="radio" name="2ans" value="Exercise"> Exercise <br>
<input type="radio" name="2ans" value="Your own self"> Your own self <br>
<input type="radio" name="2ans" value="Practice"> Practice <br>
<input type="radio" name="2ans" value="Nothing"> Nothing <br>
<hr>
Q3: Who is the teacher? <br>
<input type="radio" name="3ans" value="Mr. Lo"> Mr. Lo <br>
<input type="radio" name="3ans" value="Mr. Lai"> Mr. Lai <br>
<input type="radio" name="3ans" value="Mr. Ivan"> Mr. Ivan <br>
<input type="radio" name="3ans" value="Mr. Chow"> Mr. Chow <br>
<hr>
<input type="submit" name="Submit">

</body>
</html>
```

point page

```
<html>
<head><title>ex41b</title></head>
<body bgcolor="silver" text="black">
<body>
<font size=30 color=blue>Your total point is:</font><hr>

<?php   
    if($_POST["1ans"]=="Ed") {
        $result1=1;
    }else{
        $result1=0;
}
    if($_POST["2ans"]=="Practice") {
        $result2=1;
    }else{
        $result2=0;
}
    if($_POST["3ans"]=="Mr Chow") {
        $result3=1;
    }else{
        $result3=0;
}

    echo $_POST["result1"]+$_POST["result2"]+$_POST["result3"];

?>

<hr>
<a href="ex41a.php">Back</a>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried this code already, but if I choose the right answer I still get 0 point.... how can I make it like if there's a right answer then it will add 1 point in total of 3 points...

Q1 ans is Ed

Q2 ans is Practice

Q3 ans is Mr Chow

Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Are you running this on a webserver?

Comment: On top of other things, you're missing a closing tag `</form>` and a `<!DOCTYPE ...>`; And you'll never get 3 points, not until you stick with only one of `Mr Chow` and `Mr. Chow`

Comment: @phooji: where else would you run a PHP script which outputs HTML code?

Comment: @mkilmanas: Just trying to rule out some basic failure cases -- what's obvious to us definitely doesn't generalize to all incoming users.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is very ugly, but to solve this problem start by using the variables you have introduced instead of undefined POST variables:

```
echo $result1+$result2+$result3;
```

And here's a suggestion for a better structure:

```
$correct = array(1 => 'Ed',
                 2 => 'Practice',
                 3 => 'Mr Chow');
$result = array();
$points = 0;

for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
  if($_POST['ans'.$i] == $correct[$i]) {
    $result[$i] = true;
    $points++;
  }else{
    $result[$i] = false;
  }
}

echo $points;
```

The `$result` will now contain if the user answered correctly on each question, and `$points` is the total number of correct answers. Notice that I prefer arrays instead of numbered variable names since it's much easier to work with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
echo $result1 + $result2 + $result3;
```

instead of

```
echo $_POST["result1"]+$_POST["result2"]+$_POST["result3"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
echo $_POST["result1"]+$_POST["result2"]+$_POST["result3"];
```

To:

```
echo $result1+$result2+$result3;
```

Consider this: How are the values from your variables supposed to end up in the `$_POST` superglobal?

Answer (score 0):

you need to: `echo $result1+$result2+$result3;` rather than the post values